# Making a drop-down list of text and algebraic equations in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make a drop-down list in Excel, where every option consist of a text and an algebraic equation. The equation is only for display complementing the text.

For example, list item 1 should say:
"Pure time delay: ^(−)" (preferably without ^, and (−) in superscript).

Hence, I want to keep the professional format for the equation (not the linear one).

Pasting the content from an equation (with the professional format) in excel into a text cell does not match and the equation ends up looking weird.

So, what I'm basically asking is how to assign an equation in professional format to a cell combined with some text.

Any pointers out there on this matter?

Best regards,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be something to do with where you are getting your text from and how excel handles them. Starting from scratch in a blank cell in Excel I could type your equation, but I can't then paste that text here, as stackoverflow wants to treat it as a picture.

To enter the text I first typed ke( , I then used Insert,Symbol to add the theta, then typed the s). I then highlighted everything from ( to ) in the formula bar and then on the hme menu I clicked on the small arrow that appears just to the right of the Font text in the toolbar. (at my screen resolution the arrow is just above the theta). That expands the menu options and I could then select superscript. Then (and only then) I pressed enter to put this into the cell.

Comment: I see, and that would probably work for the equation in the example. But what about equations including other operators? Like fractions for instance, that would not work this way...

Comment: If you mean like (x+y)/x^2 yes, there's no good way of showing it in excel other than as a graphic. There are symbols for integer fractions such as 1/2 however